# Етимологія слова "ничка"

Tags: етимологія

Виникло питання щодо етимології слова "ничка" ( в значенні "схованка"). Знайшла інформацію про це слово у [Словарі українського сленгу](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53405/375282.html). Отже, ненормативно його вживати. Чому воно стало сленговим? Намагалася знайти відповідь у етимології, але не знайшла. А слово "никати" має інше значення у [Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/nykaty). Допоможіть знайти твірне слово.

Comment: Дуже дивно, що тлумачний словник 70-х не зазначає у слова _[никати](http://sum.in.ua/s/nykaty)_ значення ховати (а слів «заникати» і «заникатися» узагалі не містить). По-моєму, [доволі відомі значення](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_ZJaeHsKOg); і СУМ-20 [зазначає](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=216838&page=1011). Невже це справді неологізми (риторичне питання)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [Етимологічному словнику української мови](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf), том 4, ст. 93 подана така інформація:

> [**нИчка1**] <<казкова істота, що пряде вночі">> (з укр. ?); - неясне; можливо, пов'язане з ніч, нічка.
>
> [**нИчка2**] (у сполуці [н. непримітка] (бот.) "недоросток маленький" Ж; -очевидно, похідне утворення від никнути "припадати до землі"; назва зумовлена тим, що ця маленька рослина має витке, простягнуте стебло. - Див. ще ***нИкнути***.
>
> [**нИчка3**] - див. ***нИшкати***.

На цій же сторінці є відсилання до слова “нишкати”. Перевіряємо інформацію:

> [**нИшкати**] "Шмигати", [нИшкавка] "пролаза", [нuчка] (орн.).; можливо, пов'язане з никати <<ТИнятися>>.

У статті “никнути” (с. 87) подають таке значення:

> [**нИкнути**] "Нахилятися, нагинатися, припадати до землі; зникати, "Ходити без діла, без мети, тинятися; заглядати; [дивитися; нахилятися Ж; нюхати, нишпорити, шукати]", ник (виг.) "зирк, глядь; шасть", никлий "похилений; сумний; [слабкий, ніжний Ж]", "нижчий" До, вникати, зникати, зюікнути, зюікти, [зниксівий] "минущий" Ж, зниклий; - р. никнуть "схилятися, нахилятися; слабнути", бр. "нікнуць" "схилятися, на хилятися, [нікаць] "Шукаючи заглядати всюди; нахиляти Голову; **ховатися**>>, др. никнути "схилятися, припадати", п. "зникати", схв. "поникнути; "упасти на коліна", слн. "зникнути", стсл."нахилитися";  -ПСЛ. "схилятися, нахилятися, зникат", очевидно, генетично тотожне "з'являтися, проростати" з'являтися, проростати"

Отже, “**ничка**” — походить із “**никнути**”, що означає ховатися, відповідно і означає “**схованка**”.